# Access local html files in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to access local html files from my Django app.

These file are generated during the use of the webapp.

How can be done?
Should I store them in specific folders?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you read the Django documents about templates? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/overview/#design-your-templates

Comment: _These file are generated during the use of the webapp._ - what does that mean?

Comment: That mean are the result of a computation, launched by the webapp.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'access' them? What do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

To whom may concern, I solve it by including the html files generated inside a template.

view.py

```
filepath = 'html_file.html'
with open(filepath,'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
context = {'html_content': content}
return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{{ html_content|safe }}
```